# Suntour fork: Air side lower leg screw can't be tightened, rotates too easily

Tags: fork, torque

I tried to do a lower leg service on a Suntour Auron 35 fork, for the first time. When re-assembling, I was unable to tighten the air side screw to the 6 Nm that Suntour specifies in this video:

Well before reaching 6 Nm, everything starts to rotate freely. However, I can still easily unscrew it.

Should I be worried?

---

Note that the video has typos. When it shows the air side, the caption says "cartridge side" and vice versa. Is there reliable information about tightening torques?